# CSS: Why does the background color not apply to titles?

Tags: html, css

Last time I designed a website was 256 years ago when HTML 4 was the standard, but I still remember some HTML tags and wanted to quickly build a website. However, I ran into some problems I cannot explain. I wanted to create a simple website with some articles, so I used the `section` tag and the `article` tag and defined a different `background-color` for the articles. The `background-color` however does not apply to the headers within the articles, and also the corners are not round. Also the elements in the navigation `div` are not bolder, why?

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

* {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  background-color: E2ECE8;
}

body {
  margin-left: 2cm;
  margin-right: 2cm;
  margin-top: 0.5cm;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
}

#nav {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

article {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 21cm;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #007973;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div id="nav">
  <a href="index.html">Articles</a>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
<section id="articles">
  <article>
    <h2>December 29 2021, Dummy Post</h2>
    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
      here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
      Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
      up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
      in section 1.10.32.</p>
    <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
      from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    <h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
      you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
      of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid setting rules on `*` unnecessarily; in this case you probably want that background-color to be on `body`.  What you were seeing as the background not applying to headers was the `* {background-color: #E2ECE8}` rule taking precedence on child elements inside the `article`.

The border radius is there, it's just very small. Same goes for `bolder` -- it's there, it's just not as noticeably bold as `bold`.

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  background-color: #E2ECE8;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;

  margin-left: 2cm;
  margin-right: 2cm;
  margin-top: 0.5cm;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
}

#nav {
  font-weight: bold;
}

article {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 21cm;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #007973;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div id="nav">
  <a href="index.html">Articles</a> <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
<section id="articles">
  <article>
    <h2>December 29 2021, Dummy Post</h2>

    <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

    <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
    content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various
    versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by
    English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

    <h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
    There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum,
    you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary
    of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Text on the articles looks rather packed and saturated,  some proper margins, along with padding whenever needed and a couple of decent formatting wouldn't come bad for best css practices and html layout.

Comment: @AlvisonHunter you may have misunderstood the purpose of this website. This answer was not an attempt to improve the aesthetics of his layout, it was just correcting the error he asked about.

Answer (score -1):

**Hi Nils,**

Take a look at the below example to get an idea of what is going on lately with CSS and HTML tags. It is great to read that you are back to coding, this is always fun!! Cheers!

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
    margin-left: 2cm;
    margin-right: 2cm;
    margin-top: 0.5cm;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background-color: #E2ECE8;
}

#nav {
    font-weight: bolder;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bolder;
}

h2 {
    color: #093D3D;
    font-size: 17px;
}

h3 {
    color: #007882;
    font-size: 16px;
  margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}

h2,
h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: left;
    color: #586A6B;
  margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
}

article {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 600px;
  width:500px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #007973;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1ECECC;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>CSS Background Problem</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <div id="nav">
         <a href="index.html">Articles</a> | 
         <a href="about.html">About</a>
      </div>
      <section id="articles">
         <article>
            <h2>December 29 2021, Dummy Post</h2>
 <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
 
 <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
 
 <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

<h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</p>
 
 <p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
 
 <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>

<h3>Where can I get some?</h3>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.</p>
 
 <p>All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
         </article>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `background-color: transparent` is the default; setting it on `*` does nothing.